Changing the box stroke color of material design text input
I am creating an app using IntelliJ IDE and Kotlin.
I have been trying to change the attribute,
app:boxStrokeColor

of my component,
com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

But each time I have tried it ends up some default color of the Material Design Components library which has forced me to end up creating a resource in my
colors.xml 

file called,
<color name="mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color" tools:ignore="PrivateResource">#E8E415</color>

But now that means I am only able to set this once and if I change it from this aforementioned color then it changes the instance everywhere.
I do know that I can create different drawables in order to achieve my desired affect but I wanted to know if there was a different way or better way then having to implement the drawables or the method of using
<color name="mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color" tools:ignore="PrivateResource">#E8E415</color>

Without having to do it in my backend code each time or reusing a variable.
I have tried,
drawables
<color name="mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color" tools:ignore="PrivateResource">#E8E415</color>
app:boxStrokeColor="#E8E415"

Let us see some code, please.

As at today, i don't think this has been fixed with material design. Last i checked, i faced same issue.
